# How to create paid google marketplace apps?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

I am trying to create a marketplace app based on subscription model. I did write apps script code and followed the process of creating a store listing via google marketplace sdk and marked it as Paid but I did not specify the price and also see that my add on can be installed without any payment. I want to create apps like Quicklution and Jivrus formbuilder.

I did check many resources but none of them were helpful.

Comment: You need to roll out your own in-app payment system